# SQLite 64bit integers recognized as ints in jooq

Tags: java, sqlite, long-integer, jooq

I have an SQLite database that I am using with jOOQ.
When I use jOOQ's code generation tool, it builds all of the table and record classes as expected.
However, all of the SQLite `INTEGER` columns turn into `java.lang.Integer` fields in the generated code.

The problem is that SQLite `INTEGER's` can store up to a 64 bit signed integer, where `java.lang.Integer` is only a 32 bit signed integer.

Is it possible to tell jOOQ to use `java.lang.Long` (which is 64 bit signed) for these columns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, there is no such thing as an actual `INTEGER` data type in SQLite, only an [`INTEGER` affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), which can indeed store up to 64 bit signed integers. However, when you use DDL, you will typically use one of these (mostly) standard "type names", which can be used in `CREATE TABLE` statements and `CAST` expressions:

- INT
- INTEGER
- TINYINT
- SMALLINT
- MEDIUMINT
- BIGINT
- UNSIGNED BIG INT
- INT2
- INT8

In order to get jOOQ to generate a `java.lang.Long`, you will need to use one of `BIGINT` or `INT8` in your `CREATE TABLE` statement. If you use `INT` or `INTEGER`, jOOQ will assume that you really intended for storing 32 bit signed integers, and thus `java.lang.Integer` values.

#### Rewriting data types

Note that jOOQ's code generator configuration also allows you to [rewrite data types based on column names or column types](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/data-type-rewrites/):

```xml
<forcedType>
  <!-- Specify any data type from org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType -->
  <name>BIGINT</name>

  <!-- Add a Java regular expression matching fully-qualified columns.
       Use the pipe (union operator) to separate several expressions.
       If provided, both "expressions" and "types" must match. -->
  <expression>.*\.IS_VALID</expression>

  <!-- Add a Java regular expression matching data types to be forced
       to have this type. If provided, both "expressions" and "types" must match. -->
  <types>.*</types>
</forcedType>
```

Comment: While SQLite may accept those types, it doesn't seem to actually use them for anything internally.  You can definitely put 32 bit integers in an INT, with no warning or issue.  At least in my experience, it is common to use INT in the creation statements for all sized integers.
I have a number of legacy databases that do this, which make them much trickier to work with in jOOQ.

Comment: @oillio: Yes, we're aware of that. But simply making everything a long by default wouldn't be what many of the jOOQ users really want. We'll think about this - in the mean time, you can have the jOOQ code generator [rewrite data types for you](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/data-type-rewrites/)

Comment: A way to override the generator is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.  jOOQ has been a pleasure to work with, thanks for all your hard work.

Comment: @oillio: Thanks for your nice words. I'll add the link also to the answer

Comment: The main problem here ist that in order to get primary keys autogenerated, the PK column must be created as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` - which causes jOOQ to emit `int`s. `BIGINT PRIMARY KEY` columns will *not* cause SQLite to autogenerate PKs. It might be useful if jOOQ treated INTEGER PK fields differently, as a PK is probably preferred as a `long` (more than 2^31 entries can happen...)

Comment: @ChristophHenkelmann: Would you mind asking a new question with some more details? I'm not sure if your issue is strictly related to this question here.

Comment: @LukasEder actually it is - this answer is the solution to the current state of things: autoincremented PK only work when declared as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` in SQLite. jOOQ turns those fields into `Integer`s. To get `Long` the above `forcedType` definition can be applied to map anything named `id` (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

To add to @lukas Eder's response, this is a concrete example of how i solved the issue for my case.

```json
{
  "forcedTypes": {
    "forcedType": {
      /*
        Transform Sqlite's INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT columns to Long instead of Int in
            Jooq generated code.
        I name all my id columns as `[table_name]_id` (eg. select user.user_id from user),
            so I'm using a sql to return all those columns.
 */

      "name": "BIGINT",

      //language=SQLite
      "sql": """
          WITH all_tables AS (SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table')
          SELECT pti.name
          FROM all_tables at INNER JOIN pragma_table_info(at.name) pti
             WHERE lower(pti.name) = lower(at.name || '_id')
      """
    }
}
```

*Note: This is adapted from my `build.gradle.kts` file to make it a bit more readable. Unfortunately the actual version has more boilerplate code, because the `nu.studer.jooq` gradle plugin is not that kotlin friendly `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.*